# Echo value and percentage from SQL server Union query in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have an issue where I'm trying to find the percentage of two queries but want to retain the session value to echo elsewhere. let me explain.

My first union query returns a value E.G. 100

```
$sql1 = "select COUNT(*) From 
(select inc.INCIDENT_NUMBER as TICKET 
From dbo.HELP_DESK as inc
Where inc.STATUS < 3
and inc.ASSIGNED_GROUP = 'Scheduling'
UNION ALL
SELECT chg.INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID AS TICKET
FROM dbo.CHANGE as chg
WHERE chg.CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS NOT IN (1,4,5,8,9,10,11,12)
and chg.ASGRP in = 'Scheduling') num1";
```

I then want to echo the result as a session value so:

```
$SCH = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql1);
if( $SCH === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while( $Row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $SCH, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
$_SESSION['$SCH'] = $Row[0];
}
```

so far so good. However, I want to calculate the percentage based on my second union query.

```
$sql2 = "select COUNT(*) From 
(select inc.INCIDENT_NUMBER as TICKET 
From dbo.HELP_DESK as inc
Where inc.STATUS < 4
and inc.ASSIGNED_GROUP = 'Scheduling'
UNION ALL
SELECT chg.INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID AS TICKET
FROM dbo.CHANGE as chg
WHERE chg.CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS < 9
and chg.ASGRP = 'Scheduling') num2"
```

The second value is 250 as an example. So I'm trying to calculate the percentage e.g. (100/250) * 100 = 40%

```
function percentage ($sql1,$sql2)
{ 
  return ($sql1/$sql2) * 100;
}
Echo percentage
```

The last bit pulls back nothing, blank screen. There's probably a much easier way of doing this and given my relative php newcomer status, I'm probably mixing up several functions at once.

I'd appreciate a little help getting it working. Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the percentage issues, can output seperate session values.

```
select
    s.activeCount * 100 / s.totalCount as Percentage
    FROM
(select activecount = (select COUNT(*) From 
(select inc.INCIDENT_NUMBER AS TICKET
From dbo.HELP_DESK as inc
Where inc.STATUS < 3
and inc.ASSIGNED_GROUP = 'Scheduling'
UNION ALL
SELECT chg.INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID AS TICKET
FROM dbo.CHANGE as chg
WHERE chg.CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS NOT IN (1,4,5,8,9,10,11,12)
and chg.ASGRP = 'Scheduling') num), 
totalCount = (select COUNT(*) From 
(select inc.INCIDENT_NUMBER AS TICKET
From dbo.HELP_DESK as inc
Where inc.STATUS < 4
and inc.ASSIGNED_GROUP = 'Scheduling'
UNION ALL
SELECT chg.INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID AS TICKET
FROM dbo.CHANGE as chg
WHERE chg.CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS < 9
and chg.ASGRP = 'Scheduling') num)) s
```